# matlab spare matrix to python

Tags: python, matlab, sparse-matrix

I want to get a sparse matrix of dimension 16995 by 16995 in python. I have the syntax in matlab and I am not sure how can I write in python to get the same syntax as well as the output like matlab.

The matlab synttax :

```
  C = [s1 s2 s3;s4 s5 s6;s7 s8 s9];
```

where s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9 is a sparse csr matrix each of dimension 5665 by 5665 . How can  I write the same syntax in python to get the exact dimension and a sparse matrix.

I tried using block but it does not give me the right dimension.
As requested the matlab version of the code :

Comment: The more efficient solution uses sp.sparse.bmat

Answer (score 0):

This is best achieved through `numpy.hstack` and `numpy.vstack`.

```py
import numpy as np

C = np.vstack([
  np.hstack([s1, s2, s3]),
  np.hstack([s4, s5, s6]),
  np.hstack([s7, s8, s9]),
])
```

Comment: This does not work. I got a 3 by 3 matrix of  ndarray object of numpy module.

Comment: What is the type of s1, s2, etc? Can you include the code for their declaration please

Comment: s1 and s2 are sparse matrices .Also, I have updated my post and have added the matlab version of the code

Comment: show the python code

Comment: You need sp.sparse.hstack for sparse matrices.

Comment: I solved it. I have added the solution on my post

Comment: sparse matrices require sparse functions, not numpy ones

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
  C = vstack([
  hstack([s1, s2, s3]),
  hstack([s4, s5, s6]),
  hstack([s7, s8, s9])
  ],format='csr')
```